# Buggy paper-tabs in Polymer 1.0

Tags: html, polymer, web-component

I recently made the shift from Polymer 0.5 to 1.0 and one aesthetic problem I noticed right away was the behavior of clickable elements, especially `paper-tabs` and `paper-button`. When clicked, the text resizes in a weird and abrupt manner like so:

[image]

As you might've noticed, at one point I clicked the tab and it became active yet the bar underneath did not slide under it.

How can I get them to be more smoother and 'in place'? Like this:

[image]

Following is the code for the `paper-tabs`:

```
       <paper-toolbar id="mainToolbar" class="tall">
            <div class="top title flex">[[headerTitle]]</div>
            <my-tools class="top"></my-tools>
            <div class="bottom">
                <paper-tabs selected="[[selected]]" noink class="tabs">
                    <paper-tab id="discover"><a href="/">DISCOVER</a></paper-tab>
                    <paper-tab id="learn"><a href="/learn">LEARN</a></paper-tab>
                    <paper-tab id="explore"><a href="/explore">EXPLORE</a></paper-tab>
                </paper-tabs>
            </div>
        </paper-toolbar>
```

Comment: Can you show us the code you have so far?

Comment: @BenThomas Added it just now.

Comment: try giving the `paper-tabs` element a width of 100% that improves it a lot for me.

Comment: when you click on the tab youre making the text bold and it looks like its expanding the texts width and heightt.. give a test and don't make the text bold to see what you get

Comment: @Tasos So I modified the height from the default 100% to `initial` and it solved the vertical shaking.

Comment: Put that in your answer or post it as answer. someone else might have the same issue in the future

Comment: @Tasos the vertical shaking is fixed but the glitch where I click the tab but it doesn't become active, still persists

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at `paper-tab.html`, you can change:

```
:host(:focus) .tab-content {
  opacity: 1;
  font-weight: 700;
}
```

and remove the change in `font-weight` to:

```
:host(:focus) .tab-content {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

Comment: is there a way you can do this in your project so you don't need to rewrite the paper-tab.html file?

Answer (score 1):

You can define your classes for elements below <paper-tab>.

```css
#resolutionTabs span.tab {
  font-weight: 500 !important;
  font-family: 'Open Sans';
  font-size: 16px;
}
```

```html
<paper-tabs id="resolutionTabs" attr-for-selected="data-resolution" selected="{{resolution}}">
  <paper-tab data-resolution="1080x1920"><span class="tab">1080x1920</span></paper-tab>
  <paper-tab data-resolution="1920x1080"><span class="tab">1920x1080</span></paper-tab>
  <paper-tab data-resolution="1280x1024"><span class="tab">1280x1024</span></paper-tab>
  <paper-tab data-resolution="1024x1280"><span class="tab">1024x1280</span></paper-tab>
</paper-tabs>
```